# Installing Command & Conquer 3 on a new computer

Tags: command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars

I've passed on my Command & Conquer 3 game to a friend but they can't play the multi-player game online as it says the CD key is still in use. Anyone know how I can reset this?

The game was originally installed on a laptop that has been wiped and is long gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option really is to [contact EA](https://customersupport.ea.com/loginapp/cp/login.do?skin=ea&locale=en_US&curl=http://support.ea.com/app/home&surl=http://support.ea.com/ci/pta/login&p_next_page=ask).  Some companies are pretty good about CD key transfers.  Relic, for instance, is pretty forgiving about Company of Heroes.

I can't find a reference to anyone who has done this successfully, however.  It's an old game, so you may be out of luck.

Comment: Cheers, interesting - I login using my old account and my browser tells me the server is redirecting me in a way that will never complete. And I can't login to new site as seems to think my email address doesn't exist even though it just sent me a password reminder to that address from link you provided. I'll let me friend create an account and try to get EA to work with him.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of issues altogether, you can add your key to your Origin account and play the digital download version. This removes the per-PC serial registration system.